# Prove the following identity of Gamma : $\frac{\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{8})}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})\Gamma(\frac{5}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{8})}$

Tags: gamma-function

> Prove 
>   $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{8})}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})\Gamma(\frac{5}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{8})}$$

We know that :

$\Gamma(x+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(2x)!\sqrt{π}}{4^{x}x!}$

So : $\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8})$ !!

Comment: Use the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 4):

By the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula),  if $z\notin\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\Gamma \left({z}\right) \Gamma \left({1 - z}\right) = \dfrac \pi {\sin \left({\pi z}\right)}$$
so you can evaluate $\Gamma(\frac{1}{8})\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})$ and $\Gamma(\frac{3}{8}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{8})$ and verify that
$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{8})\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{8})\Gamma(\frac{5}{8})}=1+\sqrt{2}.$$

P.S. See also [Evaluate $\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126799/evaluate-sin-frac-pi8-and-cos-frac-pi8) or the [Silver ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio) (due to user 493905).

Comment: $1+ \sqrt 2$ = $\delta_s$

Comment: What is $\delta_s$?

Comment: $\delta_s$ is the Silver Ratio (a Metallic Number).

Comment: @user493905 Thanks for the reference!