# trigonometric expressions as algebraic numbers

Tags: trigonometry

which trigonometric expressions give results which are rational or expressible as surds? is there a complete set? are there infinite? for example, the well known $sin(30)=1/2$, and a range of others like $sin(45)=\sqrt2/2$, I know of, but how many are there? it seems like multiples of 30, 18, and other fractions of 360 degrees give results as surds more often.

Comment: As I recall, the set of values $a\pi$ for algebraic numbers $a$ produces algebraic numbers $\sin(a\pi)$.

Comment: ok thanks! (thats in radians right?)

Comment: @abiessu, are you saying $\sin(\sqrt2\pi)$ is algebraic?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176889/for-which-angles-we-know-the-sin-value-algebraically-exact

Comment: @BarryCipra: I may have misunderstood other discussions on this topic; my answer is "I thought so, but now I'm second-guessing..."

Comment: @abiessu, to quote a comment by Robert Israel from my previous comment's link, "If $x/\pi$ is an algebraic irrational, $\sin(x)$ is transcendental by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem."

Comment: @BarryCipra: so the correct answer is to replace $a$ as a rational instead of $a$ as algebraic in my initial comment...