# $f(f(z)) = z , f(\exp(z)) = \exp(f(z)) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations, tetration, complex-dynamics

While talking about tetration with my friend the following idea (re)occured.

Equation A

$$f(f(z)) = z , f(\exp(z)) = \exp(f(z)) $$

or variations of it like the weaker

Equation B

$$f(f(f(f(z)))) = z , f(\exp(\exp(z))) = \exp(\exp(f(z))) $$

Now clearly if f satisfies equation A it also satisfies equation B, but not necessarily the other way around.

What are analytic solutions $f(z)$ for some local region $D$ bounded by a jordan curve $C$ where $z,f(z),\exp(z),f(\exp(z)),\exp(f(z))$ are in $D$ ( $D$ being the interior part of the curve $C$) , that satisfy

$f(f(z)) = z , f(\exp(z)) = \exp(f(z)) $

?

without the trivial $f(z)=z$ ofcourse.

***edit***

One idea is to use Carleman matrices and Diagonalize.

Consider the Carleman matrix of size $n \times n$ for the exp :

$$M_n(\exp(z)) =A_n$$.

Now diagonalize

$$A_n = P_n \times D_n \times P_n^{-1}$$

Then we can define $f(z)$ by Carleman matrix of size $n \times n$ :

$$M_n(f(z)) =B_n$$.

$$B_n = P_n \times D*_n \times P_n^{-1}$$

where $D*_n$ is the diagonal matrix of size $n$ with all $-1$ on the diagonal.

This way we get

$$B_n^2 = D°$$

where $D°$ is the (diagonal) Carleman matrix of $id(z)$.

and

$$A_n B_n = B_n A_n$$

as desired.

Now let $n$ increase and hope for convergeance.
And nonzero radius.

And ofcourse we assume diagonalization is always possible.

Might this work ? How to prove it ? What is the result ?

This method does seem to prefer the carleman interpretation of tetration ofcourse, which is not my bias but a consequence of the idea of using eigenvalues and matrices by lack of other " simple " ideas.

---

***edit***

Maybe look at it this way :

$$G(z^2) = \exp(G(z))$$

Then $G(z^{-1})$ is associated with $f(f(z)) = z$...
Unless the case $G(z^{-1}) =G(z)$ for all $z$ or the unless for the solutions $z$ such that $G(z^{-1}) =G(z)$.

And ofcourse $z=0$ does not work there.

---

Comment: Analytic functions with $f(f(z))=z$ are, I think, very sparse, even without the extra condition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews +1 yes I am aware they are rare. Extra reason to find them.

Comment: Also posted on mathoverflow : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442520/ffz-z-f-expz-expfz

Comment: Well, if you can't solve just $f(f(z))=z,$ you'll probably not be able to solve this.

Comment: There are linear fractional transformations that satisfy $f(f(z)) = z$, but of course they do not satisfy $f(\exp(z)) = \exp(f(z))$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What are you talking about ? I know infinite families of infinite families that solve $f(f(z))=z $ I said analytic , not entire ofcourse. The entire solutions are $f(z) = C - z$ or $f(z)=z$ and then you have meromorphic solutions like $f(z)=\frac{C}{z}$ or $f(z) = \frac{ax + b}{x + d}$ where $a+d=0$ and you also got $f(z) = \sqrt{1-z^2}$ as a solutions and many many more. $f(z) = inverse_g(1-g(z))$ always works. Ofcourse this does not solve the problem.

Comment: $g^{-1}(h(g(z))$ where $h$ is an involutions is tricky, because you have to be careful about the domain, for example, when $g(z)=e^z.$ I had questions about the domain of $f(z)$ when $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}.$ Took mean a while to see that we could use as the domain  $\operatorname{Re}z>0,$ excluding the reals $\geq 1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know how to solve $f(-z)^2  = 1 - f(z)$ :)

Comment: Maybe this helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula
In particular if some truncation is justified.

Comment: I made an edit with a proposed method ; carleman matrices ...

Answer (score 1):

*not an answer but an extended comment towards @mick's comment of Mar 16*

Hmm, I like to see the "Carleman-matrix" mentioned - a long & intense hobby of mine for the understanding of problems on powerseries. But I want to mention two obstacles which are rarely, if at all, mentioned and/or considered.

First: the concept of Carlemanmatrices (working on problems of powerseries) is always meant to use matrices of two-dimensionally *infinite size*. Truncations to finite size, of course when approximate solutions by software are attempted, are not always smoothly extensible to the case of infinite size. A very nice example of unavoidable miscalculation has been brought to my knowledge by Ed Sandifer on an example of L. Euler, where he proposes a powerseries solution for the logarithm, based on increasing polynomials (which would today be expressed by increasing finite Carlemanmatrices), but which is *systematically* false, as Euler has shown by himself. (Ed Sandifer's "HEDI" pages,Dec 2007, "A False Logarithm series"). I've discussed this with my understanding of matters in [this essays](https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/FalseLogarithm.pdf)
There are other examples, where the extension from the "polynomial approximations" (finite-sized Carleman-matrix) to the "powerseries-solution" seem to work (for the alms of "tetration"), possibly the Ansatz of A. Robbins for the `slog()` is here an example.
The commonly known Schroeder/Koenigs-solution for the iterated exponential $\exp(z)-1$ and other series allowing triangular Carleman-matrices (and their diagonalization) is another example for the concept to be working. But the examples with the attempt to diagonalize Carleman-matrices for powerseries ***with*** constant term (not triangular matrices) - well, I don't know whether (or: how far) they are already safe...

Second, we find cases, where we need Integral expressions to formulate complete solutions for some power series problems. (The Ecallè-solution for the `slog()` for instance uses an Integral)
Eri Jabotinsky has been an exponent and early pioneer for the use of Carlemanmatrices. But for some cases he proposed to use *extended* Carlemanmatrices, which model then Laurent series or even twoway infinite powerseries. I've found one article where he introduced thus a Carlemanmatrix extended to index $-1$ - but it seems that he couldn't/didn't finish the complete model. To see better what I mean with this (as far I could understand the problem correctly) I have written a small essay with a proposition for the extension of the $\exp()$-series (and its Carlemanmatrix) to the $-1$-index; that small note does not solve the problem but puts it a bit more explicite than I could do this here. See "[problem with Bell-matrix](https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ProblemWithBellmatrix.pdf)" at my homepage.

---

I think a progress in this concept of Carleman-matrices for the problem of tetration should be made by answering/solving the two mentioned problems here.