# Given that $x$ is a rational number, is $\sin(x\pi)$ always expressible through radicals?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

This is a theory I just thought of and I am wondering if there is truth to it.

Here is the logic that I am working upon:

Using Euler's formula, you can deduce that
$$ (-1)^x = i\sin(x\pi)+\cos(x\pi)$$
and thus,
$$\sin(x\pi) = Im((-1)^x)$$
$$\cos(x\pi) = Re((-1)^x)$$

Now, let us let x be a rational number expressible as $\frac pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers

Using this, we can calculate $(-1)^x$ by doing
$$ a+bi=(-1)^{\frac pq} $$
$$(a+bi)^q=(-1)^p$$
Now, $(a+bi)^q$ can be expanded into a polynomial and grouped into real parts, and since $p$ is an integer, $(-1)^p$ will be either $1$ or $-1$.

We now group it into 2 polynomial parts, the real and imaginary, and set the imaginary part equal to $0$ and the real part equal to $1$ if $p$ is even and $-1$ if $p$ is odd.

Here is my example:

$$x = 2/3$$
$$(a+bi)^3=(-1)^2=1$$
$$a^3-3ab^2+i(3a^2b-b^3)=1$$
which gives us the two equations:
$$a^3-3ab^2=1$$ $$3a^2b-b^3=0$$

Now we have a system two equations with two variables and so they can just be solved using algebra, and since $Im((-1)^x)=Im(a+bi)=b$ and $\sin(x\pi) = Im((-1)^x)=b$, then can't we just solve for b with the system of equations and then that is our answer for $\sin(\pi x)$

Since it is a polynomial then shouldn't be be expressible through radicals and thus, shouldn't all $\sin(x\pi)$ be expressible through radicals?

Comment: A similar question: [Is the value of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$ expressible by radicals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/572215/19661)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the numbers $\sin(\pi x)$ (for rational $x$) *are* always expressible by radicals, but in a somewhat trivial sense.

Namely, if we write $x = m/n$, and let $\zeta_{2n} = \cos \pi x + i \sin \pi x,$
then $$\sin (\pi x) = \frac{1}{2 i} (\zeta_{2n} - \zeta_{2n}^{-1}),$$
and $\zeta_{2n}$ is a radical, since $\zeta_{2n}^{2n} = 1$.

You can see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAngles.html) for
a more detailed discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Although such real numbers $\sin(\pi x)$ are algebraic, they are not necessarily expressible by radicals on that account.  In other words, being a root of a polynomial does not imply that root is expressible by radicals, as Galois and Abel showed us.

To conclude that they are expressible by radicals amounts to showing that the Galois group of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(2 \cos \frac{\pi}{n} )$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is solvable, for each integer $n \ge 2$.  An argument that this Galois group is actually Abelian (hence solvable) is found in Sec. 4 of Wolfdieter Lang's recent paper [The field $\mathbb{Q}(2 cos \frac{\pi}{n} )$, its Galois group, and length ratios in the regular n-gon](http://www.itp.kit.edu/~wl/EISpub/A187360paper.pdf), as summarized on page 22 there.

Comment: However, it does for $q\le4$, correct? So if $x=p/q$ when expressed in irreducible form has this condition, $\sin(\pi x)$ will be expressible in terms of radicals?

Comment: Isn't a rational power of a number a "radical" by definition? So $(-1)^{p/q}$, $p$, $q$ integer is a radical, no?

Comment: @hardmath : I don't think you make your case.  Yes, some algebraic numbers are not expressible by radicals, but the question is whether these particular algebraic numbers are expressible by radicals, not whether _all_ algebraic numbers are expressible by radicals.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You are right that I did not answer the Question posed in the title, but rather I was in the first instance responding to the body, where the OP invites an opinion as to whether "the logic that I am working on" is sound, and specifically to the final sentence, "Since it is a polynomial, shouldn't [it] be expressible through radicals...".  I've now supplied a reference for the more difficult argument needed.