# When $\cos{n^{\circ}}$ can be expressed in real radicals?

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

So, the question is: $\cos{n^{\circ}}$ can be expressed in real radicals iff $3 \mid n$? Is it true? The first part is easy: if $3 \mid n$ we can express it, because $\cos{36^{\circ}}=\cos{\pi\over{5}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}$, thus we can express $\cos{18^{\circ}}$, and now also can $\cos{48^{\circ}}=\cos{(18^{\circ}+30^{\circ})}$. From it follows that we can express $\cos{3^{\circ}}$, because $3={48\over 16}$. Thus we can express $\cos{3k^{\circ}}$ for any $k\in \mathbb N$, using formula of $\cos(nx)=...$.
The main question is: why can't we express it if $n\neq3k$? Or we can?

Comment: Are you familiar with constructible numbers/straight-edge and compass constructions?

Comment: See [this 26 September 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3977641) and the following math StackExchange question: [rational angles with sines expressible with radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66100/rational-angles-with-sines-expressible-with-radicals).

Comment: I realize that you probably want $n$ to be an integer. Yet you may find [this (=17-gon)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon) at least somewhat interesting.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information

Comment: @StefanSmith I think it was really about $3^\circ$ as halfing $48^\circ$ four times.

Comment: @Berci : my bad.  Thanks.  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Would you like to turn your comment into an answer? That would be helpful in dealing with related questions such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871668).