# How to express $\cos(20^\circ)$ with radicals of rational numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

In showing that the trisection of an angle with ruler and compass is not possible in general one shows that $\cos(20^\circ)$ cannot be constructed (thus the angle $60^\circ$ cannot be trisected) by determining its minimal polynomial, which is $8x^3-6x-1$.

Solving $8x^3-6x-1=0$ yields a solution $x_1=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{16}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}i}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}i}$. Expressing $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{16}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}i}$ and $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}i}$ in polar form yields $x_1=\cos(20^\circ)$.

Is it possible to express $\cos(20^\circ)$ with radicals without complex numbers?

Comment: As $\Bbb R\subseteq \Bbb C$, how can a complex number be expressed by two different numbers?

Comment: This is answered by the links in [Dave L. Renfro's comment to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622707/#comment-1311972).

Comment: If you have an irreducible cubic with real coefficients and all 3 roots are real, this is the ***casus irreducibilis*** and the roots **can't** be expressed in real radicals.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises in the fact that the polynomial you got has 3 real roots and is irreducible over the rationals. It is an example of *casus irreducibilis,* which essentially shows that certain algebraic numbers whose minimal polynomial is of degree 3 or higher are real themselves but require complex numbers in order to be expressed in radicals.

This is pretty much as simple as you can get:

$$
\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{1-i\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{1+i\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt[3]{2}}
$$

...In which the imaginary parts simply cancel out leaving a real number. Again, *you cannot remove the complex numbers from this expression.*

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cos (20^\circ) = \cos (\pi/9) = -\frac12 (-1)^{8/9} \left(1+(-1)^{2/9}\right)
$$

Comment: If the only problem be $i$ in the record, then OP can just make $i\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{-3}$.